# How to move from one panel to another within the same frame without using CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have one frame and many panels. I am not using `CardLayout`, so I do not want answers regarding that. The logic used by me is :

```
gpanel3.setVisible(false);   
gpanel.setVisible(true);

f.add(gpanel);
```

This works, when I go from first panel, to second. But when I go from 2nd panel to third, it doesn't work. The panels are passed into the classes through constructors from the frame.

Comment: *"I am not using codeLayout,.."*  If by `codeLayout` you mean `CardLayout` then, it is the best approach for this.  I doubt many will be willing to expend effort making anything else work, without a good reason as to *why* the app. is not using `CardLayout` ..

Comment: `removeAll()` followed by `add( newPanel, ... )` and then the traditional `revalidate()` and `repaint()` should do the trick if you do not want to use `CardLayout`

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. Closing this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`CardLayout` is a great layout but has a disadvantage for me: you must create your `JPanel`s before and add them into your 'cards'. It's a problem if your panels are too much so you would create your panel 'on fly'.

Usually, I do something like this.

```
public void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
    removeAll();
    add(panel);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

If you want to implement a back\forward navigation, create a `List` of `JPanel` and everytime user change panel push the JPanel into your list and increment a specific index. So, you can undo your view calling

```
changePanel(list_panels.get(index_to_show));
```